# Build list from column names Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, dataframe

So I am operating on a rather large set of data. I am usign Pandas DataFrame to handle this data and am stuck on an efficient way to parse the data into two formatted lists

HERE IS MY DATAFRAME OBJECT

```
            fet1    fet2    fet3    fet4    fet5
stim1       True    True    False   False   False
stim2       True    False   False   False   True
stim3       ...................................
stim4       ...................................
stim5       ............................. so on
```

I am trying to parse each row and create two lists. List one should have the column name of all the true values. List two should have the column names of the false values.

example for stim 1:

```
list_1=[fet1,fet2]   
list_2=[fet3,fet4,fet5]
```

I know I can brute force this approach and Iterate over the rows. Or I can transpose and convert to a dictionary and Parse that Way. I can also create Sparse Series objects and then create sets but then have to reference the column names separately.

The only problem I am running into is that I am always getting Quadratic O(n^2) run time.

Is there a more efficient way to do this as a built in functionality from Pandas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I don't think this is a good way to do whatever it is...

Comment: I am trying to build a list of feature information so I can create a basket file to feed into Orange association rule learner parser. So the file has to look like this.

Comment: fet1, fet2, fet3, fet4, tag

Comment: A Series of lists is unidiomatic, and not very useful, but it does sound like what you need in this particular case. See my answer for a second possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> df
       fet1   fet2   fet3   fet4   fet5
stim1  True   True  False  False  False
stim2  True   False False  False   True
>>> def func(row):
        return [
            row.index[row == True], 
            row.index[row == False]
        ]
>>> df.apply(func, axis=1)
stim1    [[fet1, fet2], [fet3, fet4, fet5]]
stim2    [[fet1, fet5], [fet2, fet3, fet4]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is still row by row Basis. I knew there was a way to do it with the built in API but I am new to PANDAS. Thank you for your help. And I was also needing to parse this way because I had to do extensive filtering before this step and DataFrame helped me parse everything very quickly. Thanks Again.

Comment: And this gives me O(n) parsing.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be faster. I do not think a more succinct solution is possible.

Fast (not row-by-row) operations can get this far.

```
In [126]: (np.array(df.columns)*~df)[~df]
Out[126]: 
      fet1  fet2  fet3  fet4  fet5
stim1  NaN   NaN  fet3  fet4  fet5
stim2  NaN  fet2  fet3  fet4   NaN
```

But at this point, because the rows might have variable length, the array structure must be broken and each row must be considered individually.

```
In [122]: (np.array(df.columns)*df)[df].apply(lambda x: Series([x.dropna()]), 1)
Out[122]: 
                  0
stim1  [fet1, fet2]
stim2  [fet1, fet5]

In [125]: (np.array(df.columns)*~df)[~df].apply(lambda x: Series([x.dropna()]), 1)
Out[125]: 
                    0
stim1  [fet3, fet4, fet5]
stim2  [fet2, fet3, fet4]
```

The slowest step is probably the Series constructor. I'm pretty sure there's no way around it though.